# How to define the leak period date in SonarQube using the API?

Tags: api, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.0

Has anyone defined the leak period date in SonarQube using the API?

I have looked at the Web API (localhost:9000/web_api/) but have not seen a section that details this operation.

Any advise is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setting+the+leak+period) go to Administration > General Settings > General > Differential Views. If you want to do it with a script, have a look at api/properties web services.

Comment: curl -u admin:passwd  -X POST "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9000/api/properties?id=sonar.timemachine.period1&value=2017-3-3&resource=Test:mybranch"

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried this url,

```
curl -u d****@****.com:****** -X POST https://*****.com/api/properties?id=sonar.timemachine.period1&value=2018-06-01&resource=AdManager
```

and my response code is;

```
{"err_code":200,"err_msg":"property created"}
```

But, the property is not updated. Is there a way I can see why this failed? The logs don't seem to mention anything.